# codeigniter how can I get access to config/form_validation.php data?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have duplicated data across my `config/form_validation.php` and my `controller`.
the **field** and **label** from `form_validation` is the same that I specify in my `controller` for the **id**, **name** and **placeholder**

Do I have to extract that data to yet a third location and reference it in both of these?

**application/config/form_validation.php**

```
$config = array(
                 'register' => array(
                                    array(
                                            'field' => 'register_username',
                                            'label' => 'Username',
                                            'rules' => 'trim|required|exact_length[5]'
                                         ),
.....
```

**application/controllers/mycontroller.php**

```
        $this->viewdata['register_username'] = array(
            'id'            => 'register_username',
            'name'          => 'register_username',
            'type'          => 'text',
            'placeholder'   => 'Username'
        );
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you have your data duplicated in the controller itself. You might find it easier to use [Jamie Rumbelow's model/schema libraries mashup](https://github.com/williamknauss/schema_base_model_magic).

This will clean up your model/application structure as a whole. The model extension library itself allows for the automation of CRUD methods.